# how to bind session data to a label in ascx without using code behind

Tags: c#

I am having a popup implemented using divs in asp.net 4.0. I have to show some static text along with a field account number which I am getting from session. Is there any way that i can bind session value to lable in ascx file wihout using code behind.

this is ascx code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="BtnVerifyContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue" OnClick="BtnVerifyContinue_Click" />
 <div id="addAccVerifyPopUp" runat="server">
  <div id="popupVerifyContent" style="font-weight: bold; padding: 10px; margin:4px 7px;" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblpopUptext" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 <br />
 </div>
 </div>
```

I have to show text in label lblpopuptext, something like

> You have successfully added electric Meter" + **AccountNumber** + "
> An
>   emails has been sent to the robertm@gmail.com

Where I want to get the value of  **AccountNumber** from session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblpopUptext" runat="server">
      <%=Sesssion["AccountNumber"]%>
 </asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks , It worked. A small edit in the syntax: <%#(Session["AccountNumber"]%>

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" 
Text="You have successfully added electric Meter" + <%# Eval("AccountNumber")%> + "
An emails has been sent to the robertm@gmail.com">
</asp:Label>
```

or if the value is stored in the session:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblIB" runat="server" 
Text="You have successfully added electric Meter" + <%# Eval(Session["AccountNumber"])%> + "
An emails has been sent to the robertm@gmail.com">
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: I am getting the following error upon using the above code(specified for session)**the best overload method match for System.Web.Ui.templateControl.Eval(string) has some invalid arguments**

Comment: Ok, try it without Eval